# Dialog box visible by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create a Dialog box but its visible by default..

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2uc1jn83/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">

  <select id="division">
    <option></option selected>
    <option>National</option>
    <option>Central</option>
    <option>Northeast</option>
    <option>Western</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Filter">
        <div style="text-align:left">
            <select size="5">
                <option value="1">Item #1</option>
                <option value="2">Item #2</option>
                <option value="3">Item #3</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#division").change(function() {

    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog({
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 1000,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,

      })
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });

})
```

Comment: The div id="dialog" is a dialog box..Its visible by default..below the other div..

Comment: Rather than creating jsfiddle, Kindly mention your script here.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110127/318125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you even understand your code? This looks like you copy/pasted it from somewhere. There's an anonymous function too much and the construction of the dialog should not happen on change of the `<select>`. This event should open the dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#division").change(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog({
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 1000,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false

   });
});
```

You can see it in action here: https://jsbin.com/vejawinigu/edit?js,output

Comment: thanks..I had another element with the same id and that was the confusion